# How to ensure function is only run once in a jupyter session?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I use jupyterlab. I have a function that delete a element of a list, dependent on some hyperparameters. In regular python this works every time I deploy the code. In jupyter, when I run the code more than once it give me: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

I tried to force a kernel restart on the beginning of my script like this:

```
from IPython.display import display_html
display_html("<script>Jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart()</script>",raw=True)
```

but a) it did not work and b) I think there should be an more efficient way.

Can I just put a conditional on my function `assert_valid_config(data_config)` that only deploys it on the first run?

What is the most efficient way to solve this? Right now I just might put a try-catch block around it, but I hope there is a more general solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the Part where you initialise your list everytime in jupyter? It sounds to me, that x gets removed the first time and list stays that way (which is kinda they point in jupyter).

You could try and put `assert_valid_config(data_config)` into a seperate block in jupyter and not run it everytime.